# Incorrect syntax near 'in'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Why am I getting an error statement here with the following? incorrect syntax near 'in'?

```
INSERT INTO Staging.dbo.progress execute('SELECT ID
    FROM Staging.dbo.tempstudents WHERE StartTerm in' + @progressReportTerm);
```

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/67533179/2029983

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server, `execute` does not take expressions.  So you need to construct the query beforehand:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

select @sql = '
SELECT ID
FROM Staging.dbo.tempstudents
WHERE StartTerm in ' + @progressReportTerm;

INSERT INTO ODS_Staging.dbo.progress
    exec(@sql);
```

You no doubt have a good reason for using dynamic SQL here.  However, that is probably not really a requirement.  And the dynamic SQL might be introducing a SQL injection risk.  It is definitely introducing a potential for hard-to-debug syntax errors.

Comment: Don't do this, it's not that it *might* be open to injection, it **will** be. Use a table table parameter.